# How do I avoid overwriting when saving a recorded file to a site subfolder?

Tags: javascript, php, audio

folks! I'm trying to implement an audio recorder within my website. I've just got to make the recorded file to be saved to a subfolder in my website (/speaking_audios). The main problem is that every recording savings I tested are being done with the same name: audio.wav. For example, I save a recent recording and there in the subfolder there appears a file named audio.wav, past three minutes I save another recording, just that this last one overwrites the first file I saved (as it is the same name).

recorder.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>FlashWavRecorder demo</title>
  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/recorder.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h1><a href="https://github.com/cykod/FlashWavRecorder">FlashWavRecorder</a></h1>
    <p><strong>Upload requires php, i.e. example will not work on github.com</strong></p>


    <div id="recorder-audio" class="control_panel idle">
      <button class="record_button" onclick="FWRecorder.record('audio', 'audio.wav');" title="Record">
        <img src="images/record.png" alt="Record"/>
      </button>
      <button class="stop_recording_button" onclick="FWRecorder.stopRecording('audio');" title="Stop Recording">
        <img src="images/stop.png" alt="Stop Recording"/>
      </button>
      <button class="play_button" onclick="FWRecorder.playBack('audio');" title="Play">
          <img src="images/play.png" alt="Play"/>
      </button>
      <button class="pause_playing_button" onclick="FWRecorder.pausePlayBack('audio');" title="Pause Playing">
          <img src="images/pause.png" alt="Pause Playing"/>
      </button>
      <button class="stop_playing_button" onclick="FWRecorder.stopPlayBack();" title="Stop Playing">
        <img src="images/stop.png" alt="Stop Playing"/>
      </button>
      <div class="level"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="recorder-audio2" class="control_panel idle">
      <button class="record_button" onclick="FWRecorder.record('audio2', 'audio2.wav');" title="Record">
        <img src="images/record.png" alt="Record"/>
      </button>
      <button class="stop_recording_button" onclick="FWRecorder.stopRecording('audio2');" title="Stop Recording">
        <img src="images/stop.png" alt="Stop Recording"/>
      </button>
      <button class="play_button" onclick="FWRecorder.playBack('audio2');" title="Play">
        <img src="images/play.png" alt="Play"/>
      </button>
      <button class="pause_playing_button" onclick="FWRecorder.pausePlayBack('audio2');" title="Pause Playing">
        <img src="images/pause.png" alt="Pause Playing"/>
      </button>
      <button class="stop_playing_button" onclick="FWRecorder.stopPlayBack();" title="Stop Playing">
        <img src="images/stop.png" alt="Stop Playing"/>
      </button>
      <div class="level"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="details">
      <button class="show_level" onclick="FWRecorder.observeLevel();">Show Level</button>
      <button class="hide_level" onclick="FWRecorder.stopObservingLevel();" style="display: none;">Hide Level</button>
      <span id="save_button">
        <span id="flashcontent">
          <p>Your browser must have JavaScript enabled and the Adobe Flash Player installed.</p>
        </span>
      </span>
      <div><button class="show_settings" onclick="microphonePermission()">Microphone permission</button></div>
      <div id="status">
       Recorder Status...
      </div>
      <div>Duration: <span id="duration"></span></div>
      <div>Activity Level: <span id="activity_level"></span></div>
      <div>Upload status: <span id="upload_status"></span></div>
    </div>

    <form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" action="upload.php">
      <input name="authenticity_token" value="xxxxx" type="hidden">
      <input name="upload_file[parent_id]" value="1" type="hidden">
      <input name="format" value="json" type="hidden">
    </form>

    <h4>Configure Microphone</h4>
    <form class="mic_config" onsubmit="return false;">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label for="rate">Rate</label>
          <select id="rate" name="rate">
            <option value="44" selected>44,100 Hz</option>
            <option value="22">22,050 Hz</option>
            <option value="11">11,025 Hz</option>
            <option value="8">8,000 Hz</option>
            <option value="5">5,512 Hz</option>
          </select>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="gain">Gain</label>
          <select id="gain" name="gain">
          </select>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="silenceLevel">Silence Level</label>
          <select id="silenceLevel" name="silenceLevel">
          </select>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="silenceTimeout">Silence Timeout</label>
          <input id="silenceTimeout" name="silenceTimeout" value="2000"/>
        </li>

        <li>
          <input id="useEchoSuppression" name="useEchoSuppression" type="checkbox"/>
          <label for="useEchoSuppression">Use Echo Suppression</label>
        </li>

        <li>
          <input id="loopBack" name="loopBack" type="checkbox"/>
          <label for="loopBack">Loop Back</label>
        </li>

        <li>
          <button onclick="configureMicrophone();">Configure</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
    <?php
$save_folder = dirname(__FILE__) . "/speaking_audios";
if(! file_exists($save_folder)) {
  if(! mkdir($save_folder)) {
    die("failed to create save folder $save_folder");
  }
 }

function valid_wav_file($file) {
  $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
  $header = fread($handle, 4);
  list($chunk_size) = array_values(unpack('V', fread($handle, 4)));
  $format = fread($handle, 4);
  fclose($handle);
  return $header == 'RIFF' && $format == 'WAVE' && $chunk_size == (filesize($file) - 8);
}

$key = 'filename';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
$upload_name = $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"][$key];
$type = $_FILES["upload_file"]["type"][$key];
$filename = "$save_folder/$upload_name";
$saved = 0;
if($type == 'audio/wav' && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.wav$/', $upload_name) && valid_wav_file($tmp_name)) {
  $saved = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $filename) ? 1 : 0;
}

if($_POST['format'] == 'json') {
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  print "{\"saved\": $saved}";
} else {
  print $saved ? "Saved" : 'Not saved';
}

exit;
?>
```

js/main.js

```
    $(function () {
  var $uploadStatus = $('#upload_status'),
    $showLevelButton = $('.show_level'),
    $hideLevelButton = $('.hide_level'),
    $level = $('.control_panel .level');

  var CLASS_CONTROLS = "control_panel";
  var CLASS_RECORDING = "recording";
  var CLASS_PLAYBACK_READY = "playback_ready";
  var CLASS_PLAYING = "playing";
  var CLASS_PLAYBACK_PAUSED = "playback_paused";

//  Embedding flash object ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  setUpFormOptions();
  var appWidth = 24;
  var appHeight = 24;
  var flashvars = {'upload_image': 'images/upload.png'};
  var params = {};
  var attributes = {'id': "recorderApp", 'name': "recorderApp"};
  swfobject.embedSWF("recorder.swf", "flashcontent", appWidth, appHeight, "11.0.0", "", flashvars, params, attributes);

//  Handling FWR events ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  window.fwr_event_handler = function fwr_event_handler() {
    $('#status').text("Last recorder event: " + arguments[0]);
    var name, $controls;
    switch (arguments[0]) {
      case "ready":
        var width = parseInt(arguments[1]);
        var height = parseInt(arguments[2]);
        FWRecorder.uploadFormId = "#uploadForm";
        FWRecorder.uploadFieldName = "upload_file[filename]";
        FWRecorder.connect("recorderApp", 0);
        FWRecorder.recorderOriginalWidth = width;
        FWRecorder.recorderOriginalHeight = height;
        $('.save_button').css({'width': width, 'height': height});
        break;

      case "no_microphone_found":
        break;

      case "microphone_user_request":
        recorderEl().addClass("floating");
        FWRecorder.showPermissionWindow();
        break;

      case "microphone_connected":
        FWRecorder.isReady = true;
        $uploadStatus.css({'color': '#000'});
        break;

      case "permission_panel_closed":
        FWRecorder.defaultSize();
        recorderEl().removeClass("floating");
        break;

      case "microphone_activity":
        $('#activity_level').text(arguments[1]);
        break;

      case "recording":
        name = arguments[1];
        $controls = controlsEl(name);
        FWRecorder.hide();
        setControlsClass($controls, CLASS_RECORDING);
        break;

      case "recording_stopped":
        name = arguments[1];
        $controls = controlsEl(name);
        var duration = arguments[2];
        FWRecorder.show();
        setControlsClass($controls, CLASS_PLAYBACK_READY);
        $('#duration').text(duration.toFixed(4) + " seconds");
        break;

      case "microphone_level":
        $level.css({width: arguments[1] * 50 + '%'});
        break;

      case "observing_level":
        $showLevelButton.hide();
        $hideLevelButton.show();
        break;

      case "observing_level_stopped":
        $showLevelButton.show();
        $hideLevelButton.hide();
        $level.css({width: 0});
        break;

      case "playing":
        name = arguments[1];
        $controls = controlsEl(name);
        setControlsClass($controls, CLASS_PLAYING);
        break;

      case "playback_started":
        name = arguments[1];
        var latency = arguments[2];
        break;

      case "stopped":
        name = arguments[1];
        $controls = controlsEl(name);
        setControlsClass($controls, CLASS_PLAYBACK_READY);
        break;

      case "playing_paused":
        name = arguments[1];
        $controls = controlsEl(name);
        setControlsClass($controls, CLASS_PLAYBACK_PAUSED);
        break;

      case "save_pressed":
        FWRecorder.updateForm();
        break;

      case "saving":
        name = arguments[1];
        break;

      case "saved":
        name = arguments[1];
        var data = $.parseJSON(arguments[2]);
        if (data.saved) {
          $('#upload_status').css({'color': '#0F0'}).text(name + " was saved");
        } else {
          $('#upload_status').css({'color': '#F00'}).text(name + " was not saved");
        }
        break;

      case "save_failed":
        name = arguments[1];
        var errorMessage = arguments[2];
        $uploadStatus.css({'color': '#F00'}).text(name + " failed: " + errorMessage);
        break;

      case "save_progress":
        name = arguments[1];
        var bytesLoaded = arguments[2];
        var bytesTotal = arguments[3];
        $uploadStatus.css({'color': '#000'}).text(name + " progress: " + bytesLoaded + " / " + bytesTotal);
        break;
    }
  };

//  Helper functions ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  function setUpFormOptions() {
    var gain = $('#gain')[0];
    var silenceLevel = $('#silenceLevel')[0];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      gain.options[gain.options.length] = new Option(100 - i);
      silenceLevel.options[silenceLevel.options.length] = new Option(i);
    }
  }

  function setControlsClass($controls, className) {
    $controls.attr('class', CLASS_CONTROLS + ' ' + className);
  }

  function controlsEl(name) {
    return $('#recorder-' + name);
  }

  function recorderEl() {
    return $('#recorderApp');
  }


//  Button actions -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  window.microphonePermission = function () {
    recorderEl().addClass("floating");
    FWRecorder.showPermissionWindow({permanent: true});
  };

  window.configureMicrophone = function () {
    if (!FWRecorder.isReady) {
      return;
    }
    FWRecorder.configure($('#rate').val(), $('#gain').val(), $('#silenceLevel').val(), $('#silenceTimeout').val());
    FWRecorder.setUseEchoSuppression($('#useEchoSuppression').is(":checked"));
    FWRecorder.setLoopBack($('#loopBack').is(":checked"));
  };

});
```

js/recorder.js

```
    (function(global) {
  var Recorder;

  var RECORDED_AUDIO_TYPE = "audio/wav";

  Recorder = {
    recorder: null,
    recorderOriginalWidth: 0,
    recorderOriginalHeight: 0,
    uploadFormId: null,
    uploadFieldName: null,
    isReady: false,

    connect: function(name, attempts) {
      if(navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
        Recorder.recorder = window[name];
      } else {
        Recorder.recorder = document[name];
      }

      if(attempts >= 40) {
        return;
      }

      // flash app needs time to load and initialize
      if(Recorder.recorder && Recorder.recorder.init) {
        Recorder.recorderOriginalWidth = Recorder.recorder.width;
        Recorder.recorderOriginalHeight = Recorder.recorder.height;
        if(Recorder.uploadFormId && $) {
          var frm = $(Recorder.uploadFormId); 
          Recorder.recorder.init(frm.attr('action').toString(), Recorder.uploadFieldName, frm.serializeArray());
        }
        return;
      }

      setTimeout(function() {Recorder.connect(name, attempts+1);}, 100);
    },

    playBack: function(name) {
      // TODO: Rename to `playback`
      Recorder.recorder.playBack(name);
    },

    pausePlayBack: function(name) {
      // TODO: Rename to `pausePlayback`
      Recorder.recorder.pausePlayBack(name);
    },

    playBackFrom: function(name, time) {
      // TODO: Rename to `playbackFrom`
      Recorder.recorder.playBackFrom(name, time);
    },

    record: function(name, filename) {
      Recorder.recorder.record(name, filename);
    },

    stopRecording: function() {
      Recorder.recorder.stopRecording();
    },

    stopPlayBack: function() {
      // TODO: Rename to `stopPlayback`
      Recorder.recorder.stopPlayBack();
    },

    observeLevel: function() {
      Recorder.recorder.observeLevel();
    },

    stopObservingLevel: function() {
      Recorder.recorder.stopObservingLevel();
    },

    observeSamples: function() {
      Recorder.recorder.observeSamples();
    },

    stopObservingSamples: function() {
      Recorder.recorder.stopObservingSamples();
    },

    resize: function(width, height) {
      Recorder.recorder.width = width + "px";
      Recorder.recorder.height = height + "px";
    },

    defaultSize: function() {
      Recorder.resize(Recorder.recorderOriginalWidth, Recorder.recorderOriginalHeight);
    },

    show: function() {
      Recorder.recorder.show();
    },

    hide: function() {
      Recorder.recorder.hide();
    },

    duration: function(name) {
      // TODO: rename to `getDuration`
      return Recorder.recorder.duration(name || Recorder.uploadFieldName);
    },

    getBase64: function(name) {
      var data = Recorder.recorder.getBase64(name);
      return 'data:' + RECORDED_AUDIO_TYPE + ';base64,' + data;
    },

    getBlob: function(name) {
      var base64Data = Recorder.getBase64(name).split(',')[1];
      return base64toBlob(base64Data, RECORDED_AUDIO_TYPE);
    },

    getCurrentTime: function(name) {
        return Recorder.recorder.getCurrentTime(name);
    },

    isMicrophoneAccessible: function() {
      return Recorder.recorder.isMicrophoneAccessible();
    },

    updateForm: function() {
      var frm = $(Recorder.uploadFormId); 
      Recorder.recorder.update(frm.serializeArray());
    },

    showPermissionWindow: function(options) {
      Recorder.resize(240, 160);
      // need to wait until app is resized before displaying permissions screen
      var permissionCommand = function() {
        if (options && options.permanent) {
          Recorder.recorder.permitPermanently();
        } else {
          Recorder.recorder.permit();
        }
      };
      setTimeout(permissionCommand, 1);
    },

    configure: function(rate, gain, silenceLevel, silenceTimeout) {
      rate = parseInt(rate || 22);
      gain = parseInt(gain || 100);
      silenceLevel = parseInt(silenceLevel || 0);
      silenceTimeout = parseInt(silenceTimeout || 4000);
      switch(rate) {
      case 44:
      case 22:
      case 11:
      case 8:
      case 5:
        break;
      default:
        throw("invalid rate " + rate);
      }

      if(gain < 0 || gain > 100) {
        throw("invalid gain " + gain);
      }

      if(silenceLevel < 0 || silenceLevel > 100) {
        throw("invalid silenceLevel " + silenceLevel);
      }

      if(silenceTimeout < -1) {
        throw("invalid silenceTimeout " + silenceTimeout);
      }

      Recorder.recorder.configure(rate, gain, silenceLevel, silenceTimeout);
    },

    setUseEchoSuppression: function(val) {
      if(typeof(val) != 'boolean') {
        throw("invalid value for setting echo suppression, val: " + val);
      }

      Recorder.recorder.setUseEchoSuppression(val);
    },

    setLoopBack: function(val) {
      if(typeof(val) != 'boolean') {
        throw("invalid value for setting loop back, val: " + val);
      }

      Recorder.recorder.setLoopBack(val);
    }
  };

  function base64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

    var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
      var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

      var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    return new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
  }


  global.FWRecorder = Recorder;


})(this);
```

I couldn't expose all the files above, cause there was no more space left. Well, I just want to individualize each saved file. It can be that way: username.randomidcode or something like that.

Comment: posted enough code? just create a unique file name something like  `$filename = md5(uniqid() .rand()) '.wav';`

Comment: @Dagon be a little careful with this on heavily trafficked sites.   (LOL!!!! inside joke)

Comment: @Dagon, there are more files like  recorder.php, sync.html, upload.php, js/main.js, js/swfobject.js, js/recorder.js, recorder.swf (I don't know what it is for), I couldn't show them all up above. And I don't know if I can send them to you by email for a deeper analysis. But I think this is not necessary, as my question was so dumb.

Comment: @Dagon I think you forgot a dot after `.rand())`. Do I just replace this line of code in my upload.php file? What about saving to the subfolder /speaking_audios?

Comment: Ok @Dagon, solved issue. What is the problem @BareNakedCoder?